# Magento API Error: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: php, api, magento, magento-1.7

I am using the Magento SOAP API Version v2 and occasionally get a "Unable to connect to the remote server" response from the API in my application. The error is very intermittent. Is there anything I can do to resolve this issue or is there anything I can check to understand why Magento is throwing this error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: seems like a server issue

Comment: I have reviewed the logs and nothing shows up there. I also have no reported connectivity issues for the server. Is there anything you can think to help isolate the issue?

Comment: @stitz any progress on this? I'm getting same error.

Comment: After additional investigation, I see this happening in relation to the Magento site being up to date with its SSL certs and security hardening and the system making the API calls, being older and possibly unable to communicate over new SSL protocols.